# Encrypted names in decompiled C#

Tags: .net, reflector, .net-reflector, dotpeek

After I decompiled a C# DLL, I got obfuscated names. How do I make them friendlier?

```
internal class #=q_koQQBVg_L17jD21WqVoWTKogS6iAxIVV4z7fVJYFPbQHpq5RL4asPxgytMqVUV9{
private string #=qtiNXLJTkmAsXt34BDA7ADjLv0A20d865ejHCoExwakY=;

private int #=qCxpPdOlqW4fFiR45y1um1EwJ4UPgfF0eaYnOxUvWXeE=;

private int #=qOjSTwxD2By1oqZp8jRWLqGPjneXfL5E3b$piHt7ILxE=;

private string #=qNkVdXOoWzjsjO$hxF6ugvSS8BlmPhAtqMIUp2tZDVZY=;

private string #=q2R91FyBmLI8WY4e63nMIHe__08TXNxhy48mIgiGYjBY=;

public int #=q5jQCQ8HF1R2hAxHYEDAKTg==()
{
    return this.#=qCxpPdOlqW4fFiR45y1um1EwJ4UPgfF0eaYnOxUvWXeE=;
}}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Is it your DLL or a third-party's? This code could be obfuscated.

Comment: Maybe no, because it only with internal classes. Public classes have notbroken names.